# How to change directory in AWS Lambda shell?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cd

The `cd` command doesn't exist on AWS Lambda shell. I get this:

```
which cd
Command failed: which cd
which: no cd in (/var/lang/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin:/opt/bin:/var/task)
```

How can I change directory in AWS Lambda if `cd` isn't installed? Is there a way I can download `cd`?

Comment: `cd` is a shell builtin, not a separate command. You're doing something wrong. Maybe add some details about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with your scripting language.

- Node.js : You can use [process.chdir()](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_chdir_directory)
- Python: You need to use [os.chdir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir)

But it is recommended to create your own directory and then navigate to it.